# Laravel - Running Jobs in Sequence

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, laravel-queue, laravel-horizon

I am learning Laravel, working on a project which runs Horizon to learn about jobs. I am stuck at one place where I need to run the same job a few times one after one.

Here is what I am currently doing

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Subscriptions;
class MailController extends Controller
{


    public function sendEmail() {
        Subscriptions::all()
        ->each(function($subscription) {
            SendMailJob::dispatch($subscription);
        });
    }
}
```

This works fine, except it runs the job's across several workers and not in a guaranteed order. Is there any way to run the jobs one after another?

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for, as you mention in your question, is job chaining.

[From the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#job-chaining)

> Job chaining allows you to specify a list of queued jobs that should be run in sequence. If one job in the sequence fails, the rest of the jobs will not be run. To execute a queued job chain, you may use the withChain method on any of your dispatchable jobs:
>
> ```
> ProcessPodcast::withChain([
>     new OptimizePodcast,
>     new ReleasePodcast
> ])->dispatch();
> ```

So in your example above

```
$mailJobs = Subscriptions::all()
    ->map(function($subscription) {
        return new SendMailJob($subscription);
    });

Job::withChain($mailJobs)->dispatch()
```

Should give the expected result!

**Update**

If you do not want to use an initial job to chain from (like shown in the documentation example above) you should be able to make an empty `Job` class that that has `use Dispatchable;`. Then you can use my example above

Comment: Thanks for the answer, nood question, where is `Job` class coming from.

Comment: Hey josh, your solution worked well. But when one job fails, the entire chain stops.

Comment: Hi Vish, yes this is an unfortunate downside. It might be acceptable still if you engineer your jobs not to fail. What I mean by this is: you should treat a failed job as a bug in the application (rather than an expected exception). So you can use try, catch, validation etc... to avoid the job actually failing. Of course, this is a design decision and you will have to consider what is best for your situation! :)

Comment: Thanks, i am trying Redis throttle also.

Comment: A specific feature of chaining is that the next job in the chain is only run if the previous job does not fail. That's not a disadvantage; that is designed and expected behaviour. To run a series of jobs in a sequence with no dependency on success, send them all to a the same queue with a single worker running on that queue. The worker will only be able to process one job at a time.

Comment: A simple case when you want to run many jobs in sequence, but NOT give up on subsequent jobs if one job fails, but instead merely collect failures and report them somehow: you are invoking an external service that takes a while to process each request, and you are only allowed to run one request at a time; if you send another request while previous request is still being processed, the new request will get rejected. So you want "wait for current job to complete before starting next", but NOT "require previous job to succeed before starting remaining jobs".

Answer (score 2):

Everything depends on how many **queue workers** you will run.

If you run **single queue worker**, those `jobs` will be processed in the order they were queued. However, if you run **multiple queue workers**, obviously they will be run in same time. This is how queues should work. You add some tasks and they might run in same time in different order.

Of course if you want to make sure there is a **pause** between those `jobs`, you could inside `each` add some [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) but assuming you are running this in controller (what might be not a good idea because what in case you have million subscriptions) it might be not the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for a solution like dispatch->chain([new MailJob($item1), new MailJob($item2), new MailJob($item3)])

Comment: Chaining does what you describe it doing in your question, but you state that is not what you want This answer provides the functionality you have asked for. It should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add an extra info on @Josh answer, if one of your jobs implemented `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue` interface, other jobs in the chain must implement `ShouldQueue` interface, otherwise they will not be chained.

For example, here if `ProcessPodcast` class implemented `ShouldQueue`, `OptimizePodcast` also must implement this interface to be included in the chain.

```php
class ProcessPodcast implements ShouldQueue {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    ...
}
```

```php
class OptimizePodcast implements ShouldQueue {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This really should be mentioned in the official documentation.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is Job Chaining.

You can read all about it in the Laravel website : [Chain](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#job-chaining)

Good luck